# Avoid repeating code using similar structures C

Tags: c, function, struct

Im working in a program where I have 3 similar structures.

```
typedef struct{
  int id;
  Person p;
}Client;

typedef struct{
  int id;
  Person p;
}Employee;

typedef struct{
  int id;
  Person p;
}Provider;
```

The data made is saved in three different files. Most of the information used by the functions comes from Person p; and all are similar (Making a Client/Employee/Provider, listing them, etc).
The problem is that, because they are three different structures, I must repeat the code for every job three times to extract the info from every Person or making arrays to order the files. I can't think in a way to avoid the problem using a single code for the correct type.
Example code:

`

```
int extractNameProvider(){
  FILE *arch;
  int ret=0;
  Provider pro;
  arch=fopen("fileP","rb");
  if(arch!=NULL){
    fread(&cli,sizeof(Provider),1,arch);
    printf("%s",pro.p.name);
    fclose(arch);
  }
  else{
    ret=-1;
  }
  return ret;
}

int extractNameClient(){
  FILE *arch;
  int ret=0;
  Client cli;
  arch=fopen("fileC","rb");
  if(arch!=NULL){
    fread(&cli,sizeof(Client),1,arch);
    printf("%s",cli.p.name);
    fclose(arch);
  }
  else{
    ret=-1;
  }
  return ret;
}

int extractNameEmployee(){
  FILE *arch;
  int ret=0;
  Employee emp;
  arch=fopen("fileE","rb");
  if(arch!=NULL){
    fread(&emp,sizeof(Employee),1,arch);
    printf("%s",emp.p.name);
    fclose(arch);
  }
  else{
    ret=-1;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: As all 3 structures are strictly identical you could have one single struct and your problem is solved.

Comment: Use one structure for all. If you want to increase code readability, use `typedef` and define `Client`, `Employee` and `Provider` as same structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all `struct`s are identical, you can share a base `struct` and `typedef` in your files, something like:

```
/* base.h */
struct BasePerson{
  int id;
  Person p;
};

/* client.h */
#include "base.h"
typedef struct BasePerson Client;

/* employee.h */
#include "base.h"
typedef struct BasePerson Employee;

/* provider.h */
#include "base.h"
typedef struct BasePerson Provider;
```

Then:

```
int extractNamePerson(char *file){
  FILE *arch;
  int ret=0;
  struct BasePerson person;
  arch=fopen(file,"rb");
  if(arch!=NULL){
    fread(&person,sizeof(struct BasePerson),1,arch);
    printf("%s",person.p.name);
    fclose(arch);
  }
  else{
    ret=-1;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: This does have one caveat: It possible to assign between types. For example, assign `Client` to `Employee`. This could be problem, if their `id` fields are semantically different.